# Benefits to defining multiple AJP connectors in tomcat?

Tags: tomcat

Is there any reason to define multiple AJP connectors in tomcat? Is it wasted resources by doing so?

Answer (score 2):

Well, sure, there are potential uses, if you potentially need to have different config parameters on different connectors.

But, whether it makes sense for your deployment?  If you don't see a need for it, then you probably don't need extras.  Is there a specific use case you're contemplating?

Comment: No, this is a configuration done by a contractor. Can't see any reason for the separate AJP connectors but wanted to see if there was some rationale beyond obfuscating the configuration.